# How to find the end of image while dragging in imageview

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, android-imageview

I have a imageview and using bitmap i'm displaying the image. Pinch zoom is done by matrix. For zooming i'm using "**Matrix.postScale**" method. While panning(dragging) the image i need to limit the dragging. when it reach the end of the image i need to stop the dragging.

While zooming the image got expand but the height and width of imageview as well as bitmap remain same. how can i find while reaching the end of image while dragging.

The code and xml i given below.

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    />
```

Java code is here

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
       switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(!IsZoomMode){
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(0,0);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

             mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(nTimerCountM < 30 &&  !bEnabledTaggingM)
             {              
                 nTimerCountM = 0;
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);                   
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                IsZoomMode = true;
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }                 
            }
          }
            break;
        }
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);         
  }               
        return true;        
    }  
    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
```